# Spring social vs javascript (facebook authentication )

Tags: java, javascript, spring, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I am developing a native mobile application (for ios ) & a web application that can use facebook authentication to register.

I want to know what is the adequate solution to make the authentication?

Should I use spring social or javascript if I want to share the authentication fonction in the both applications ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to use JavaScript as Javascript is LightWeight to execute in clientsite end And Regarding Authentication : Facebook itself will take care of the security and will give u the response. So, Why to give burdern to your application using Spring Social .

Use AddToThis to implement the Social Networking .